# How update the ruby version on a old rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rbenv

I have a rails 3 app that was made with 2.0.0-p0 ruby.

Now i would like to update just the ruby to 2.2.2

I changed already the local and global ruby on rbenv to 2.2.2.

> There is a way or i have to keep using the 2.0.0-p0 on this app?

Comment: You can run it with whatever you want.

Comment: right so why when i try to start the ap aways show this message:

rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.0.0-p0

Comment: You still need to install your bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have switched to another version of Ruby and you are probably using a different gemset (probably an empty one). Try running:

```
bundle install
```

Note that after switching to a newer version of Ruby, some of your old code might not be compatible, i.e. need debugging.

Hope this help!